# Compatibility version spring cloud, r2dbc

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, r2dbc, spring-data-r2dbc

I try to use spring with r2dbc

here my build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.2.0.M4'
    id 'java'
}

apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/snapshot" }
    maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/milestone" }
}

ext {
    set('springCloudVersion', "Greenwich.SR2")
}

dependencies {

     compile('io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt:0.9.1')

    //implementation 'io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt:0.9.1'

    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-config'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-gateway'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client'



    //runtime 'io.r2dbc:r2dbc-pool:0.8.0.M8'
    implementation 'io.r2dbc:r2dbc-postgresql:1.0.0.M7'
    compile 'io.r2dbc:r2dbc-pool:1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot.experimental:spring-boot-starter-r2dbc:0.1.0.M1'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot.experimental:spring-boot-starter-data-r2dbc:0.1.0.M1'



    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'io.projectreactor:reactor-test'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-test'
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:${springCloudVersion}"
    }
}
```

When a call is done to findAll of repository, this error happen

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.springframework.transaction.reactive.TransactionSynchronizationManager.currentTransaction()Lreactor/core/publisher/Mono;

update version to snapshot seem to fix issue about transaction

Comment: A Hoxton milestone should come out this week that will be compatible

Comment: I am getting the same error while using Postgres r2dbc. Can anyone help

Comment: Update to Hoxton.M1, get same erro

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in M1 `spring-data-r2dbc`, provided by `0.1.0.M1` of `spring-boot-starter-data-r2dbc` - you'll need to use the snapshot builds for now instead.

So change:

```
implementation 'org.springframework.boot.experimental:spring-boot-starter-data-r2dbc:0.1.0.M1'
```

to:

```
implementation 'org.springframework.boot.experimental:spring-boot-starter-data-r2dbc:0.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT'
```

...and you should be good to go.

Worth noting that, at the time of writing at least, the relational reactive stuff (anything r2dbc based) is *very* bleeding edge and not at all something to use in production; the natural implication of that is that snapshot builds are required to work around bugs and instabilities from time to time. This will likely change in the future.